# How do I convert a vpa number/symbolic number into binary format in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I guess it's for most of the people quite an easy one but I still have no idea about it...
Let's make an example: I have the number

```
 a=vpa('123456789123456789')
```

or also

```
 a=sym('123456789123456789')
```

This number is saved in a correct way as a symbolic number, however if I convert it to double by typing

```
 b=double(a);
```

I get a calculation error; For this reason if I then use the method

```
 dec2bin(b),
```

I don't get the exact result; So does anyone have an idea how to get the correct binary representation of a?
You'd help me a lot - thank you very much! :)

Comment: Using `double(a)` beats the whole purpose of `vpa`. This seems to be a hard problem:) Unless a better option is found: you can always use `floor(log2(a))` to get the highest nonzero bit, then compute `a-2^floor(log2(a))`, and repeat until you get bored of it. `log2(a)` is one of the few numerical functions that works with `sym`s.

Comment: "I get a calculation error" – it'd be a big help if you shared the error with us. Also, `123456789123456789` is bigger than `flintmax` so the representation in double precision is not guaranteed to be exact.

Answer (score 1):

Until a better solution is found, you can brute-force a binary representation, making use of the fact that `log2()` works for symbolic arrays.

You can successively search the highest non-zero bits of `a` like so:

```
a = vpa('123456789123456789');

onebits = [];
onebit = floor(log2(a));
while onebit>=0
   onebits = [onebits onebit];
   a = a - 2^onebit;
   onebit = floor(log2(a));
end

% construct binary representation
a_bin = zeros(1,max(double(onebits))+1);
a_bin(onebits+1) = 1;   %take care: coeff of 2^0 will be index 1
a_bin = fliplr(a_bin);  %put highest bit first
```

The result will be the binary representation of your *integer* `a`. You can convert to a string with `num2str()` or perhaps `sprintf('%d',a_bin)` if you wish.

If you use a sufficiently small test number (for which `bin2dec` is applicable, i.e. at most 52 bits large), you'll see that `bin2dec(sprintf('%d',a_bin))` will indeed restore your original integer.

You can do the same procedure with floats, and stop once a sufficiently small bit is reached. You just have to be careful when storing the binary pattern, to interpret the indices correctly.